# .NET Core SqlException:an error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm seeing an exception in Mac OS High Sierra (latest version) 10.13.5 when trying to connect to a MSSQL database using Entity Framework Core:

> SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the
>   server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.
>   (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake
>   failed)

I've updated to the latest version of .NET core:

```
dotnet --version: 2.1.300

dotnet --info: .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.300
 Commit:    adab45bf0c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.13
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.13-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.0
  Commit:  caa7b7e2ba

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  1.0.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

I've found a few similar exceptions after a quick google search, but nothing on the most recent version of OSX with the latest version of .NET core installed.

Is there a possibility this a bug in the latest version? I've tested on Windows with the same source code and had no issues.

Here are my references in the project file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone landing here to find a solution. Below is the solution that worked for me.

## Environment

**Database:** Microsoft SQL Server 2019 - Hosted on Amazon Web Services (AWS)

**.Net Core:** .Net Core SDK v3.1.401

**Operating System**: macOS Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101)

## Action Being Performed

I was trying to migrate EF Core models and update the database via the following commands

```
dotnet ef migrations add initDBMigration --context myDBContext
```

```
dotnet ef database update
```

## Error Raised

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

## Solution

The primary issue was that AWS uses SSL secured connection via it's root certificate and the dotnet ef tool was not able to verify or download the root certificate.

So you need to manually download and install the certificate and mark TrustServerCertificate as true.

**Download & Install Root Certificate**

1. Goto [Using SSL/TLS to Encrypt a Connection to a DB Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html)
2. Download the root certificate for your region or if you unsure, download the global root certificate (works with all region). Direct link to [Global Root Cert](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2019-root.pem) (valid till Thursday, 22 August 2024)
3. Install the certificate by double clicking the .pem file (which got downloaded). You can also open it via "Keychain Access"
4. Ensure "Keychain:" is selected to "System"
5. Click "Add" to install the certificate.

[image: Add Certificate Dialog]

**Modify the SQL Connection String**

1. Navigate to your connection string
2. Ensure it has `TrustServerCertificate=true`

That's it. Now perform the same action again and it should go through without this error.

Comment: TrustServerCertificate=true helped me in a similar situation.